# Create/ Export DataFrames to csv in a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, list-comprehension, export-to-csv

I have 4 DFs

```
jeep_1 = jeep_data[jeep_data['Distance (km)'] < 5]
jeep_2 = jeep_data[(jeep_data['Distance (km)'] >= 5) & (jeep_data['Distance (km)'] <= 10)]
jeep_3 = jeep_data[(jeep_data['Distance (km)'] >= 11) & (jeep_data['Distance (km)'] <= 20)]
jeep_4 = jeep_data[jeep_data['Distance (km)'] > 21]
```

I then have this code:

```
list_df = [jeep_1, jeep_2, jeep_3, jeep_4]

[item.to_csv('/Users/jacob/Desktop/Jeepney PROJECT 2/jeep_{}.csv'.format(???)) for item in list_df]
```

The list is a list of dataframes.

I want to save them with different file names jeep_1.csv, jeep_2.csv, etc.

How do I access the last element of the dataframe name jeep_2, or how can  achieve this?

Thank you !

Comment: You should **not be using a list comprehension here**, as it is for side-effects. You use a list comprehension to *make a list*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try maybe? 
Although might not be the best solution...

```
str(my_list.index(item))
```

Although this answers your question, I would probably name the files after the variables:

```
for item in my_list:
    item.to_csv('/Users/jacob/Desktop/Jeepney PROJECT 2/' + item + '.csv')
```

if you want to be more accurate you can import os, and use `os.path.join(your_dir, file_name, ".csv")`

Comment: I tried it outside the loop, but it returns this

'<built-in method index of list object at 0x11e9aceb0>'

Comment: I get that if I don't use the brackets and the item:
[my_list.index for item in my_list] - this retrun built in method
did you pass in item in the brackets?

Comment: Thanks! From your edited answer, '+ item' should be a string right? But then the items inside my_list are dataframes. How should I go about this? @Anna Semjén

Comment: @AnnaSemjén or better yet, use `pathlib`, which has a much nicer API than `os.path` (I use it for all new projects, and will often take the time to refactor old `os.path` code to use `pathlib`)

Comment: yeah, might be better the use pathlib, all depends what you want to use this for... actually I just thought about this and it is quite hard to get the variable name back as string... I mean you can dummy-force it and assign a name variable to these four frames like jeep_1.name = 'jeep_1' and so on and then just use item.name in the function... I gotta think about it to be honest how you retrieve the actual variable name as string... is the list indexing still not working?